# How do I quickly create a complex select query using Zend_Db?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

Let's say  have something like:

```
SELECT energy_produced, energy_consumed, timestamp1 AS timestamp FROM (
SELECT max(energy_produced) AS energy_produced, mid(timestamp, 1, 10) AS timestamp1 FROM tbl_energy
WHERE site_id = 1366 AND mid(timestamp, 1, 10) >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 day)
group by mid(timestamp1, 1, 10)) AS e1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT max(energy_consumed) AS energy_consumed, mid(timestamp, 1, 10) AS timestamp2 FROM tbl_energy
WHERE site_id = 1366 AND mid(timestamp, 1, 10) >= DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 day)
group by mid(timestamp2, 1, 10)) AS e2
ON e1.timestamp1 = e2.timestamp2
```

Can I just stuff it in a variable and call the sucker like $db->fetchAll($select)->toArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a SQL statement as a string to the `$db->fetchAll()` method.

You don't need to call `toArray()` on the result, because the result is already returned as an array by default.

The `Zend_Db_Table` class also has a `fetchAll()` method, but it doesn't take a SQL string, and it returns a `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` object.